# Develop an app not in english

Tags: c#, localization, windows-phone

I want develop an app localized only in italian, is it possibile?

The problem is when i submit my app to windows phone store, it ask me a description in english because the app is localized in english.

I'm not interested in a double localization, i want only change the default localization from english to italian.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes this is possible.
In your visual studio project, open the Properties. Then select the neutural language as Italian.

Properties > Assembly information > Neutral Language

[image: Properties > Neutral Language]

Comment: Is it bad that I read that as "_neutered_ language" at first?

Comment: I refrain from commenting on that :P